# Android: How check if a image exists in a IF clause?

Tags: android, image, android-drawable

I need to know how check if an image exists in R.drawable, It has to be dynamic so I have to use a string that gives me the name of the image.
I've tried with '!=null' or exist but it hasn't worked.... Help please!!!!!!!!!

```
titulo=bundle.getString("titulo");
textView = (TextView) findViewById( R.id.textView1);
textView.setText(titulo);
foto="f"+bundle.getString("numero")+"a";
System.out.println(foto);
flipper =(ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.vfFlipper);
```

this gives me the name of the image a need...

```
image = new ImageView(this);
image= new ImageView(this);
image.setImageResource(R.drawable.f00a1);
image.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
flipper.addView(image);
```

Whith this I can use the image but i need to use the variable "foto" so it can be dynamic
Thanks!

Comment: R.Drawable will have only those images that exist. If the file is not found, it complains during compile time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use `getResources` to get an instance of `Resources` class. In `Resources` class, you have [getDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getDrawable%28int%29) If the resource is not found, you would get [ResourceNotFoundException](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.NotFoundException.html) which also means the image is not found.

so the code will be something like this

```
Resource r = getResources();
Bool fileFound = true;
Drawable d = null;
try{
d = r.getDrawable(your_image_id);
}
catch(ResourceNotFoundException e){
fileFound = false;
}
if(findFound){
// Your operations
// set drawable to your imageview.
}
```

Comment: It work! but still cant reference the image_id with a file name that i create ....

Answer (score 3):

Everything in the R class is an integer - you can't create a string to represent a resource id. The closest you can get is to use `getResources()` then call...

[getIdentifier(String name, String defType, String defPackage)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

...this will allow you to find the integer which represents your resource based on the resource name.

Comment: I tried to use getResources(getIdentifier("imagen1")) but doesnt work out! am i wrong??

Comment: I tried with  int RID = this.getApplicationContext().getResources().getIdentifier(foto1, null, getPackageName());
d = r.getDrawable(RID);  but RID is always 0...

Comment: You would need to use `getIdentifier(foto1, "drawable", getPackageName())` - the second parameter is the resource type.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all! i mix the two answers and .. it work!

```
Resource r = getResources();
Bool fileFound = true;
Drawable d = null;
try{
d = r.getDrawable(getIdentifier(foto1, "drawable", getPackageName());
}
catch(ResourceNotFoundException e){
fileFound = false;
}
if(findFound){
// Your operations
// set drawable to your imageview.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
getResources().getIdentifier("icon", "drawable", "your.package.namespace");
```

check for non zero value for above statement.

```
if(0)
   //does not exists
 else
   //exists
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private boolean isDrawableImageExists(String imgName) {
    int id = getResources().getIdentifier(imgName, "drawable", getPackageName());
    return id != 0;
}
```